# Scraping a page with multiple tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape a specific page for a couple of days, to no avail. 
I am a noob both in scraping, and Python.

I am really looking for the last, large table of the page, but there aren't IDs to rely on, so I tried to scrape all tables.

I came up with this code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.freecell.net/f/c/personal.html?uname=Giampaolo44&submit=Go"

r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()
html_content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"html.parser")

tables = soup.findAll("table")

for table in tables:
        row_data = []
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
            row_data.append(cols)
        print(row_data)
```

With the above, I get a massive set of garbage in the print output (*), which was my standard output for two days.

(*) i.e.:

```
['12/155:27\xa0pm8x4\xa05309-6Streak4:07Won12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '5:27\xa0pm8x4\xa05309-6Streak4:07Won12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '8x4\xa05309-6Streak4:07Won12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', 'Streak4:07Won12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '4:07Won12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', 'Won12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '5:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', 'Streak2:49Won', '2:49Won', 'Won'], ['12/155:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '5:23\xa0pm8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', '8x4\xa013396-6Streak2:49Won', 'Streak2:49Won', '2:49Won', 'Won']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want the last you can use the index of the table tags

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.freecell.net/f/c/personal.html?uname=Giampaolo44&submit=Go'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', 'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/'}
r = requests.get(url,  headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
table =soup.select('table')[-1]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
output = []
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols]
    output.append([item for item in cols if item])
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['Date','Time','Game','Mode','Elapsed','Won/Lost'])
df = df.iloc[1:]
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @QHarr! You gave me a few topics to work on (headers, panda) and that's perfect too. 
There's only a strange behaviour when it prints: it skips rows 31 to 70. Any idea why it would do so?

Comment: Yes! Ok, I'll do that too, then. Thanks again